# Best way to keep large amounts of data (no relational database needed)

Tags: database, database-design, sql-server

I would like to know what should be the best way to keep data on a server related to the following points:

- **Chat** logs
- **Heavy text content**
- **User references** like amounts of ids (1,4,14,524,23220,...)

I'm using **PHP** and a **mysql** database but as obvious I know the topics above don't go well into mysql at large scale and maneuvering. So I would like to know how (**no, i'm not asking for your work, just your 3-line orientation**) exactly should I keep the data :)

---

Ok basically I keep my users in a sql table and another only for their friendships in which I have a field containing references related, *allegedly*, to chat logs. Now the thing is I don't actually understand whether I should have that content in a file, keep the file path in that sql field and then retrieve the file when needed, parse it and display it to the user or keep it in a database such as mongodb, raven, couch because I've never used no-sql database and wanted to know of experienced people on it. Same goes for the **heavy text content** and user references. For example, in my users table I have a field containing its friends in the following manner 1,4,5,6,14,51,... and since I've been told this is bad practice and **certainly** should be used whilst dealing with large amounts of data that would need to be changed constantly I came here in a hopeful act of guidance and enlightment.

Comment: What do you mean?  mysql is perfectly capable of handling the data you describe.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Like a chat log certainly :)

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Give me a visual representation, at large scale, of how to do this.

Comment: ...no. Nobody needs to give you a visual representation or anything. Voting to close, if you can come up with an answerable question other than "I wanna do X, do it for me" which isn't a question at all, I'll gladly vote to reopen.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Ok Jimmy, I'll put it simply this way: If you were the one to do any of those topics above what exactly would you use instead of HOW would you do it. Do you notice the slight difference? I came here because this platform is designated to this own mean: discussion of non-coded matters with other developers. What I expected, if not too much, would be something of the kind "I would use mongodb to store a lot of content because this and this" or "don't do this because." Telling me I'm asking you to do something for me is utterly ridiculous and I'm just curious, just curious:

Comment: how exactly does a chat log go well in mysql tables? xD he got two upvotes, now I want someone to show me clearly why this is viable. So, imagine I have 10000 users, should I create 10000/2 tables of sql to maintain the data or keep it by rows? xD

Comment: @user111671 none of those are particularly problematic for mysql.  Though all of them can be done a wide variety of ways depending on the requirements of the system.  Is it just logs? or is it the actual chat system? Is there free text searches on the material? What is being done with it? How much is being done with it? Is there some form of relationships between users and chat? what happens when a user is deleted? What happens when a chat message is deleted? How big is the chat message? It is also helpful to see how *you* see the relationships between data (have an er diagram?)

Comment: @MichaelT THANK YOU so much Michael for providing >useful< information! Basically my concern is just about storing the previous chat messages because I've never done something close to this before... I was thinking of picking up every past message and display it to the user just like a regular chat, then the user inter-writes and I keep pushing this new data (database or file server, hence I'm here) and then display it and so on. It's just a simple chat, and all those functionalities you refer would have an impact on it of course but I would know how to handle that just getting some orientatio

Comment: *orientation on this by now :)

Comment: @user111671 do you think you could add this information about your design and use cases into the question itself?

Comment: Who told you this site was for non-code matters? That's the opposite of what this site is for, we expect solvable problems here. Please point us to where on SO you were given that idea so we can notify whichever user referred you here for that to stop giving incorrect information about this site as they must not participate here.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa it's actually funny your questions and answers are totally unrelated to ONE SINGLE line of code :) <3

Comment: @MichaelT I've updated the question!

Comment: @JimmyHoffa btw, http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Could you be persuaded that using a relational database like MySQL is the right solution (hint: it is) or do you have to do this without a relational database as the question title suggests? Just asking because if you'd accept an answer using a relational database should perhaps take that no-RDBMS bit out of the question title.

Comment: How large is "large amounts of data"?  The number can affect the answer.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Nevermind, I am really feeling like learning something today. Whenever I'm hard on haskell I'll go and try to figure it out with you :p thank you very much, nonetheless

Comment: @psr The large amounts of data consist mainly of text as you would find on a blog (many per user) and in relation to the sequence of ids (1,24,5...) this could be _theoretically_ infinite keeping in context the number of users signed up and the possible relations between them. As you might imagine keeping huge blocks of text doesn't have the need of a relational table at all, I just need to refer them to a unique entity (or id if you will) and present them at the designated moment.

Comment: @user111671 - Well, anything could *theoretically* be infinite, but it doesn't make sense to design for infinite.  Can you give an orders of magnitude estimate of the number of comments you expect?

Comment: @psr nice answer. Well, probably around 50 ids, which means 51 relations in between each one of them and the user containing the id list.

Comment: How large is large (MB/GB/TP/PB)? What's the growth rate like (GB/Day)? *Theoretically* all DBs can grow infinitely, but few ever actually do. You might just need to better normalize your data and not actually have to worry about growth for a long time.

Comment: @SteveEvers TP and Day. After giving it some thought I believe you are right, though I just wanted to sort possibilities of endeavour in the future in relation to the data growth. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having data in the structure "1,4,5,6,14,51,..." as one data value is a [denormalized value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).

Lets say you've got something that looks like:

```
Person2's friends are: 1, 4, 5, 7, 14, 51
Person3's friends are: 1, 5, 7, 15, 50
```

And so on.  Now, lets ask the question "How many people consider person 5 to be their friend?"  Well, in a denormalized structure, you're going to fetch every person's friends and then break it apart on the delimiter, and then see if 5 is in that list, increment the count and move on.

With a relational database, you've got a structure that looks like:

```
  +--------+     +----------+
  | user   |     | friends  |
  |--------|     |----------|
  | id (pk)|<-+--| from (fk)|
  | name   |  +--| to   (fk)|
  | ...    |     +----------+
  +--------+
```

And your query to answer this question is: `select count(1) from friends where to = 5`  And, well... you're done.  You've looked over one small table that can be queried very quickly.

You've also got things if you want to cascade a delete to properly clean up the references in other tables (you've deleted user 5, make sure 5 is deleted from all the users).  There's things like consistency, isolation and durability (part of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)) that help ensure that your data maintains the proper structure.

---

NoSQL has its place.  But its not a relational database and doesn't pretend to be.  It also throws away the guarantees of ACID as a trade off for speed and ease of clustering (part of speed).  There are times you don't care about ACID and instead want the API that is provided by a nosql database (i.e. you are creating an offline instance of an application and cache all web requests - your couchdb, being accessed as a web request means that the off line one doesn't need another database).

I would suggest reading the [nosql tag](http://martinfowler.com/tags/noSQL.html) on Martin Fowler's bliki (blog + wiki).

There are solutions where nosql fits quite well.  [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) is an ancient protocol that could be thought of as one of the earliest nosql databases that exists today.  You don't access it via sql, but you do for storing data... hierarchal data.  It really works well for such data, and very fast.  Its got clustering and eventual consistency and all the things you think of when you hear about of nosql.

I wouldn't want to implement a chat system in ldap - its not the right structure.  Trying to make relational databases do what ldap does is also not a fun process.

If you are thinking of doing this as a learning experience.  Something to understand how nosql works, yea... go ahead.  Try implementing a chat system in mongo or couch.  Many people have.  I wouldn't be surprised if SE's chat isn't backed by such a data store... though I'm not sure if its couch, or mongo... the domain of noSQL is quite large in that two nosql databases may share more in common with mySQL than with each other in design.  Do chose a key-value database? or a column oriented one? or a documented oriented one? or a graph database? or... [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) lists 10 different flavors of NoSQL with 5 different sub flavors of the key-value store.

I would suggest reading from SO [SQL (MySQL) vs NoSQL (CouchDB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559411/sql-mysql-vs-nosql-couchdb) and chase the links and related links on that page.

If the data is relational... well, its likely a relational database that you are looking for (and you should make sure you learn about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).

Comment: Now THIS was an answer. Just went over all the topics and discarded thoughtfully what I was thinking wrongly. Thank you very much, I'll assure you I'll get my database normalization to its max and take a good look at your advice!

Answer (score 0):

So here's an example. An item processing system at a bank will need to store the front and rear images of the check, but a single bank can process 6,000 items in a day (12,000) images. These images do not need to be retrieved very often, only in a research case.

From the storage perspective it makes more sense to store these on the file system rather than the disk because the data is not constantly changing, access can be slower and the database size does not grow by a few hundred gigabytes a day which affects time to restore backups.

The application needs separate logic to write and load images as opposed to metadata stored in the database and this is an additional cost to develop and a separate file system must be maintained.

Storing large blocks of text in the database is probably going to be cheaper to develop and manage than writing it out to a file system, but depending on the rate of change, retrieval needs, cost of storage vs. capital to purchase it you could make a case for storing it outside the database.

As a side note, storing lists in a single column of a database creates nightmares of  programmers who have to parse them when they need a single value. Use the R in relational database management system to preserve sanity.

Comment: hello there, thank you for your answer, I've read it all and  althought I'm not into financial application of software I do believe you when you refer to the price of high-scaled developed products and storage of designated files. I'll also try and make things more by the R, it's a shame actually to leave it like this :p thank you again!